# How to check if webpage is accessed from localhost or from outside?

Tags: network-programming, go

1. How can I check from Go whether a webpage is accessed from localhost or from outside?
2. How can I disable some functions for external users?
3. How can I hide the whole site, like "nope, nothing here, port 8080 is closed, move along".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. To check if website is accessed from outside, check remote IP address. If it is not from 127.0.0.1 or ::1 (IPv6) then it is outside. Use function [`func (*IPConn) RemoteAddr`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPConn.RemoteAddr).
2. To disable some functions check the above condition.
3. To hide the whole site, bind your service to the localhost interface (127.0.0.1) only.

Binding

```
net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080")
```

or

```
net.Listen("tcp6", "ip6-localhost:8080")
```

Using http package

```
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
```